# Cloudflare and 1and1 : SSL Redirect not loading the UI

Tags: nginx, ssl, cloudflare, 1and1

I currently have my online store via 1and1(where I bought the domain) and our backend is hosted @ Linux cloud server using Nginx. We are using basic version of Cloudflare as frontend.

Now when we converted to https with the “wildcard” ssl certificate(GeoTrust), but we cannot get the redirects to work with the CloudFlare CDN. I have worked with 1and1 Support, but we have not found a resolution. I was hoping someone on the Cloudflare end may be able to help with the solution, but no response yet.

Bought the SSL certificate from 1and1(GeoTrust) and did the following configurations in nginx configuration

```
listen 443 ssl; 
server_name abc.com; 
ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/abc.com_ssl_certificate.cer;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/*.abc.com_private_key.key;
```

Website works for following conditions

- HTTP --> Cloudflare-->1and1-->Nginx(hosted in cloud server)
- HTTPS -->1and1-->Nginx(hosted in cloud server)

Website not working for

- HTTPS --> Cloudflare-->1and1-->Nginx(hosted in cloud server)

Comment: `*` is not going to work as a filename in the `ssl_certificate_key` directive.

Comment: So want to know why it is working without Cloudflare?

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds like a redirect loop problem. By default cloudflare connects via HTTP to your server, which then redirects it to HTTPS. Note that cloudflare does *not* automatically connect via HTTPS to your server, even when the client requests the HTTPS site via cloudflare.

To make it always connect via HTTPS change the setting "SSL" under "Crypto" to "Full" or "Full (Strict)".

Additionally if you don't use HTTP at all you can enable "Always use HTTPS", too, so Cloudflare does the redirects, otherwise Cloudflare might connect to your server via HTTPS but use HTTP for the connection between Cloudflare itself and the client.

For more information to how this works see https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-mean-